# Twitter bootstrap Row nolink in a table using ajax

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in my project. I am also using rowlink to make a row clickable.
It's working fine.

The problem is when I implemented ajax pagination. The new content loaded in this request didn't have appear with the link in the intire row.

Table Row Structure:

```
 <tr>
    <td class="nolink">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Movie", new { id = Model.Id }, null)">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkMovieId" value="@Model.Id">
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>@Model.Title</td>
    <td>@Model.Descr</td>
    <td>@(Model.Year != 0 ? Model.Year.ToString() : string.Empty)</td>
    <td>@(Model.Duration != "0" ? Model.Duration+ " min" : string.Empty)</td>
    <td>@(Model.Avaiable ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
    <td>@(Model.Sold ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
</tr>
```